# swap space used while physical memory is free

Tags: mysql, linux, io, swap

i recently have migrated between 2 servers (the newest has lower specs), and it freezes all the time even though there is no load on the server, below are my specs:

HP DL120G5 / Intel Quad-Core Xeon X3210 / 8GB RAM

free -m output:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7863       7603        260          0        176       5736
-/+ buffers/cache:       1690       6173
Swap:         4094        412       3681
```

as you can see there is 412 mb ysed in swap while there is almost 80% of the physical ram available

I don't know if this should cause any trouble, but almost no swap was used in my old server so I'm thinking this does not seem right.

i have cPanel license so i contacted their support and they noted that i have high iowait, and yes when i ran sar i noticed sometimes it exceeds 60%, most often it's 20% but sometimes it reaches to 60% or even 70%

i don't really know how to diagnose that, i was suspecting my drive is slow and this might cause the latency so i ran a test using dd and the speed was 250 mb/s so i think the transfer speed is ok plus the hardware is supposed to be brand new.

the high load usually happens when i use gzip or tar to extract files (backup or restore a cpanel account).

one important thing to mention is that top is reporting that mysql is using 100% to 125% of the CPU and sometimes it reaches much more, if i trace the mysql process i keep getting this error continually:

setsockopt(376, SOL_IP, IP_TOS, [8], 4) = -1 EOPNOTSUPP (Operation not supported)

i don't know what that means nor did i get useful information googling it.

i forgot to mention that it's a web hosting server for what it's worth, so it has the standard setup for web hosting (apache,php,mysql .. etc)

so  how do i properly diagnose this issue and find the solution, or what might be the possible causes?

Comment: With 8Gb of RAM do you even really need swap?

Comment: And, setsockopt() is a network function, which means that you should check your MySQL instance logs for more generalized errors pertaining to operation.

Comment: When it comes to swap, the kernel is smart. If some code or other memory really isn't being used, the kernel will still  page it out to make more room in memory for the disk cache, therefore increasing performance.

Comment: @L0j1k: I'm on a home computer with 8gigs, and I'd never go without swap. It can actually increase performance, for reasons stated above.

Comment: @Linuxios i was running the exact same setup and only about 40 mb of swap was used so I'm assuming the increase in swap usage isn't part of the kernel smartness for this exact issue : ), i disabled swap i will wait and see how things go! but i started to think this might have nothing to do with the issue at hand

Comment: To each his own, I suppose.

Comment: I will say that disk I/O is the biggest bottleneck in any system. The kernel is also smart about what is in memory and will not simply crash because a leak is running away with RAM. But as always in situations where you get multiple answers, the best solution is to try it out and see what you prefer in your particular situation. Not saying you are, Linuxios, but Stack Overflow has a big problem with people telling others how to smoke their cigars. :P

Answer (score 1):

As you may have realized by now, the `free -m` output shows 7603MiB (~7.6GiB) USED, not free.

You're out of memory and it has started swapping which will drastically slow things down. Since most applications are unaware that the virtual memory is now coming from much slower disk, the system may very well appear to "hang" with no feedback describing the problem.

From your description, the first process I'd `kill` in order to regain control would be the Mysql. If you have ssh/rsh/telnet connectivity to this box from another machine, you may have to login from that in order to get a usable commandline to `kill` from.

My first thought (hypothesis?) for what's happening is...

- MySQL is trying to do something that is not supported as this machine is currently configured. It could be missing a library or an environment variable is not set or any number things.
- That operation allocates some memory but is failing and not cleaning up the allocation when it does. If this were a shell script, it could be fixed by putting an event `trap` command at the beginning that runs a function that releases memory and cleans up.
- The code is written to keep retrying on failure so it rapidly uses up all your memory. Refering back to the shell script illustration, the `trap` function might also prompt to see if you really want to keep retrying.

Not a complete answer but hopefully will help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but does not the number "5736" under cached mean this is available memory? can anyone confirm me on this

Comment: Had to do a little research. I've always pretty much ignored the shared/buffers/cached columns. As usual, such attempts to improve productivity have their peril...

You are right. Under most circumstances there should be plenty of cached memory the application could appropriate. You may find this page at http://www.linuxatemyram.com/play.html helpful, particularly the notes at the end.

Comment: @AL-Kateb Yes that's right, the number in the cached row is the actual free memory you have. The remaining memory is used for the filesystem/block cache and will be used for other purposes if something needs that memory. (Thus the number in the Mem: column is rather useless, it'll usually always fill up to near 100%)